# Multiple Rails Applications on same server using Passenger. Restarting Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger, application-restart

I have two Ruby on Rails Web Applications that are running as different Virtual Hosts. They use Apache/Passenger.

My question is that when I update the code on one of the Web Applications, I need to restart Apache in order to make the changes live. Whenever this happens, it restarts the Apache instance which affects the second Ruby on Rails application.

Is there a way to have the new code of my first application go live without affecting the second application? `sudo service apache2 restart` causes both applications to restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phusion Passenger has two mechanisms to allow you to restart your Rails application.

Check out the Passenger documentation [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_redeploying_restarting_the_ruby_on_rails_application).

The basic premise is that you should have a `tmp` directory under the root of your Rails application.

By issuing: `touch tmp/restart.txt` from within the root of your Rails application, you're telling Passenger to restart the app.